# Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed wordpress using **siteground**. After the configuration, The page is having an error :

```
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/drafts30/public_html/knowledge.serviceseekingcareers.com.ph/wp-blog-header.php' 

(include_path='.:/usr/local/php53/pear') in /home/drafts30/public_html/knowledge.serviceseekingcareers.com.ph/index.php on line 17
```

Comment: Try to install from https://wordpress.org/download/

Comment: Thanks Jack, but I have to use siteground as our hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

first check wp-blog-header.php file exist. if exist then check permission.if  permissions 000 then you need to change that to 777

Comment: most probably it is issue of permission.